# Android - File Corrupts while saving

Tags: java, android

I am saving a file to disk after downloading it from server, but I believe it gets corrupted while saving on the disc. If the same file is downloaded using chrome on mac or using any other method, the file downloads and reads normally. The corruption seems to be in the saving process of the file. I am adding the code to help find out the problem. The file is a css file.

Corruption:
Some whitespace sort of characters appear when reading the file. A surprising thing that I tried and noticed is that if I reduce the BUFFER_SIZE to 32 from 4096, the file does not get corrupt, I couldn't figure out why. Also, reducing BUFFER_SIZE reduces whitespaces / corrupted characters.

Appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Thanks

```
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

// saves file to disk and returns the contents of the file.
public static String downloadFile(Context context, String filePath, String destParent) {
    String content = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    FileOutputStream os = null;
    String sUrl = Urls.makeWebAssetUrl(filePath); /// consider this my file URL
    String destFile = getContextBaseDir(context) + (destParent != null ? File.separator + destParent : "") + File.separator + filePath;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(sUrl);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            File outFile = new File(destFile);
            if (!outFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
                if (!outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to create parent directories for " + filePath);
                }
            }

            is = connection.getInputStream();
            os = new FileOutputStream(outFile);

            int bytesRead = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead, DEFAULT_ENCODING));
                os.write(buffer);
            }
            content = sb.toString();
        }
        else {
            LogUtils.LOGW(TAG, responseCode + " while connecting to " + sUrl + ": " + connection.getResponseMessage());
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "Error while downloading " + sUrl, e);
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "Error closing inputStream while downloading " + sUrl, e);
            }
        }

        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "Error flushing outputStream while downloading " + sUrl, e);
            }

            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LogUtils.LOGE(TAG, "Error closing outputStream while downloading " + sUrl, e);
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.write(buffer);
```

The problem is here. It should be:

```
os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

I don't know why you are *also* accumulating the content in a `StringBuffer` and returning it as a `String`. That won't scale, and in any cast it's redundant. Remove.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was the problem. Solved now :)